# MDT deployment and Naming machines

Tags: installation, deployment, wds

I have just setup an environment using WDS and the Microsoft Deployment toolkit to push images out to our machines.

The only thing I am now struggling with is naming the machines. I would like to just give them an incremental name like you used to be able to using wds (the variable was %[0][n]# in the machine name options) but i cant see anywhere in the deployment toolkit to do this.

There are other option like serial number, mac address etc but i really wanted an incremental number. Is there maybe a way to hack the lighttouch scripts to get this to work?

Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly what you're looking for but take a look at http://blogs.technet.com/mniehaus/archive/2009/12/06/ris-style-naming-with-mdt-2010-use-a-web-service.aspx to see how you might be able to achieve what you want.  I'm due to take a look at this to see if I can use it internally at our sites but haven't gotten to it.  It looks pretty good and a 90% possible replacement for the RIS style naming options.

Comment: thanks, that looks promising, i have a go at it this week